# Ember- 1.13 service not initialized in component

Tags: javascript, ember.js, dependency-injection, ember-cli

I have a clock service -clock.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
var ONE_SECOND = 2000;

export default Ember.Object.extend({
  time : null,
  second : null,
  tick: function() {
    var clock = this;

    Ember.run.later(function () {
      var now = new moment();
      clock.setProperties({
        time : now,
        second : now.seconds()
      });
    }, ONE_SECOND);

  }.observes('second').on('init')
})
```

which I initialize as

```
export function initialize(container, application) {
  container.optionsForType('service:clock', { singleton: true });
  application.inject('route', 'clockService', 'service:clock');
  application.inject('controller', 'clockService', 'service:clock');
  application.inject('component', 'clockService', 'service:clock');
}

export default {
  name: 'clock-service',
  initialize: initialize
};
```

I use the clock ticker to compute elapsed time ( I am using moment.js).

```
timeElapsed : function(){
    var clock = this.get('clockService').get('time');
    var createdTime = new moment(this.get('request.createdAt'));
    var duration = moment.duration(clock.diff(createdTime));
    if(duration._data.hours > 0) return duration._data.hours+" hrs";
    if(duration._data.minutes > 0) return duration._data.minutes+" mins";
    if(duration._data.seconds > 0) return duration._data.seconds+" secs";
    return duration._data.seconds;
  }.property('request.createdAt','clockService.second')
```

Now the issue is the service is being injected in components but the properties are not set.

Comment: Your code is working in common: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/moviji/edit?js,console By the way, the `time` variable in timeElapsed computation could be null at first call.

Comment: For each second there's an observer function to be re-calculated? This sounds so wrong. XD "ONE-SECOND: 2000" :D

Comment: I changed it to two thousand because I was thinking may be there was a racing condition occuring and then I forgot to change the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it to run here, with some modifications:
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sexiqu/1/edit?html,js,output

Please have a look at ClockServiceComponent.

The only thing I am doing differently from your code is using a computed property with 'clock.time' as its dependent key, so the computed property will be lazy evaluated every one second.

```
Ember.Application.initializer({
  name: 'registerClock',

  initialize: function(container, application) {
    application.register('clock:main', Ember.clockService);
  }
});

var ONE_SECOND = 1000;

Ember.clockService = Ember.Service.extend({
  time : null,
  second : null,
  tick: function() {
    var self = this;

    Ember.run.later(function () {
      var now = new moment();
      self.setProperties({
        time: now,
        second: now.seconds()
      });
    }, ONE_SECOND);
  }.observes('second').on('init')
});

Ember.Application.initializer({
  name: 'injectClockService',
  initialize: function(container, application) {
    application.inject('controller', 'clock', 'clock:main');
    application.inject('route',      'clock', 'clock:main');
    application.inject('component',  'clock', 'clock:main');
  }
});

App = Ember.Application.create();
App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({});

App.ClockServiceComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  second: Ember.computed('clock.time', function() {
    return this.get('clock.second');
  })
});
```